# Does Java use AES-NI when available?

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, instruction-set, aes-ni

I just heard of the instruction set extension AES-NI. Does Java's JIT compiler compile the application to use AES-NI if it is available to enhance performance?

And if yes, does it also do so if it is not sure that AES will be used (like when using TLS)?

Comment: I think it's not bundled with JDK, you have to download and build it yourself https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-aes-ni-performance-testing-on-linuxjava-stack#enable-intel-eas-ni-in-oracle-jvm

Comment: @Leo That was answer worthy.

Comment: @Leo I agree. Sad I can't accept a comment as answer :P

Comment: If you just accept answers because they sound plausible, you're going to make assumptions that do not hold true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not bundled with JDK, you have to download and build it yourself

See https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-aes-ni-performance-testing-on-linuxjava-stack#enable-intel-eas-ni-in-oracle-jvm

Comment: That applies to some kind of a third party NSS-based security provider. The SunJCE provider supports AES intrinsics too.

Answer (score 5):

[Java 8](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7184394) and [7u40](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8004381) and later include support for x86 AES intrinsics for the built-in SunJCE provider, <strike>but the feature is not enabled by default</strike> (it is).

Search [globals.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp) for "AES":

```
product(bool, UseAES, false,                                              \
        "Control whether AES instructions can be used on x86/x64")        \
...
product(bool, UseAESIntrinsics, false,                                    \
        "Use intrinsics for AES versions of crypto")                      \
```

You can enable the feature by passing the `-XX:+UseAES -XX:+UseAESIntrinsics` options to the virtual machine.

Comment: Are you sure? Testing on previous versions showed that it was turned on. If you are right, then Oracle switched tactics. Note my close vote for dupe.

Comment: @owlstead I just tested with `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` and it's indeed enabled by default. The flags are likely modified somewhere else in the code, overwriting the values initialized here. The question is definitely a dupe though.

Comment: I think they get changed after the presence of AES-NI is detected. Note that on the first CPU's that contain the instruction, that detection may fail...

Comment: Note: you need to use the Java server VM to enable intrinsics.